# Issue getting last record with most recent date - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

As the title says I have this issue trying to get that record, my query works directly in PHPMyAdmin but when I use it in the code with PHP it gets the second last record

My **second last** record has this values:

`id_record` = `17292`
`id_user` = `6`
`my_date` = `2016-12-31 11:09:08`

My **last** record:

`id_record` = `17618`
`id_user` = `6`
`my_date` = `2017-01-05 13:37:21`

This is the query I'm using to achieve this

```
SELECT id_record FROM my_table WHERE my_date = (SELECT MAX(my_date) FROM my_table WHERE id_user = 6 ORDER BY id_record DESC LIMIT 1)
```

When I use this query directly in PHPMyAdmin it works fine it shows the record with id `17618` but in the code in PHP it works but it gets the second last record (`17292`), I have no idea why is happening this, do you have some idea?, I hope you can help me, thanks.

This is the PHP code

```
$last_record = mysql_query("SELECT id_record FROM my_table WHERE my_date = (SELECT MAX(my_date) FROM my_table WHERE id_user = 6 ORDER BY id_record DESC LIMIT 1)") or die (mysql_error());
$last_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_record);
$last_record = $last_record['id_record'];
```

Comment: First off, here is simpler SQL: `select * from my_table where id_user = 6 order by my_date desc limit 1`.  Secondly, you've shown ZERO PHP code so you are praying that someone here can hack into your computer and read your code?

Comment: I added the PHP code

Comment: Does the issue still occur if you change the SQL to what I said? One thing to check for in your code would be multiple uses of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` because it fetches one record every time you call it. If you have some sort of complex looping mechanism which runs a query per row of another query and are constantly re-using `$last_record` then that can definitely cause issues if you are not careful.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Why you use a subquery ? you can directly select the last record like this:

```
SELECT id_record 
FROM my_table 
WHERE id_user = 6 
ORDER BY id_record DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This was my query before I posted but it was the same, it works but get the second last, I have no conditions before use that code, I delete the cache and still not working

Comment: what datatype are the fields. show as the output from **show create table my_table**

Comment: Type `int(11)` and `date`